# IndexOutOfRangeException vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

```
Private Sub Button73_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Button73.Click
    Dim serienaam
    Dim oud
    Dim aantal As Integer
    Dim tt
    Dim bedrag As Integer
    Dim totaal As Integer

    serienaam = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    oud = ComboBox2.SelectedItem
    aantal = TextBox7.Text


    tt = "" & serienaam & "  " & oud & "  " & aantal & "  "

    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT '" & oud & "' FROM series Where naamserie = '" & serienaam & "' ", con)

    Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If sdr.Read = True Then
        Dim week = sdr.Item(" '" & oud & "' ") '\\gives a IndexOutOfRangeException... 
        bedrag = week
        totaal = totaal + bedrag * aantal



        sdr.Close()
        'Label14.Text = totaal
        ListBox1.Items.Add(tt)

    End If



End Sub
```

When I run this it gives a `IndexOutOfRangeException` on

```
If sdr.Read = True Then
        Dim week = sdr.Item(" '" & oud & "' ") \|/<---\|/gives a IndexOutOfRangeException... 
        bedrag = week
        totaal = totaal + bedrag * aantal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I'll try to answer this in an understandable fashion.

The main issue is your SQL query.

```
New SqlCommand("SELECT '" & oud & "' FROM series ...
```

What your query will look like is this. Oud will in this example be "ID":

```
SELECT 'ID' FROM series...
```

What you are telling the database is this:

For each row you can find send back the string 'ID'.

What you really want is this, notice the lack of apostrophes:

```
SELECT ID FROM series...
```

This will return the value in the Column named ID.

Run this query in this link and you'll understand better: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

```
SELECT 'CustomerID', CustomerID FROM Customers;
```

As a bonus, code that I believe will work. Just put it in the same place as before.

```
Dim oud as String
oud = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT " & oud & " FROM series Where naamserie = '" & serienaam & "' ", con)
Dim week = sdr.Item(oud) 'As rinukkusu said
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to quote the column name at:

```
Dim week = sdr.Item(oud)
```

Comment: that is not really the point. it goes wrong at: ' sdr.Item(" '" & oud & "' ")' ive already tried many things but it doesn't work '"& oud &"' gives back the wrong value. it doesn't give the columnu value but the column name... pleasse help me to solve this

Comment: I actually do think that this is the point. You should atleast try it before dismissing it.

Comment: also sdr.item(oud) wouldn't work since (oud) is a variable and not the column name, it is the variable that holds the column name. that's why it needs quotes

Comment: so it IS the column name alas the right thing you need, but case got solved anyway~